# Mysterious behavior with printf

Tags: c

I am very much new to C coding. Just started learning for about one month. Everything was going smoothly but then suddenly DEV C++ started acting strangely. The problem is that now it doesn't show variable values. That means I write a C code, compile it and after running the program i see what i put in the code is not showing correctly. It was okay a few days ago but now i don't know how or what cause it is totally screwed.

Here's a example of the problem. A very simple basic C code. But the end result is messed up.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char a = 'J';
    int x = 15;
    float y = 9.75;

    printf("%c\n%d\n%f", &a,&x,&y);

    getch();
}

Output: shows something like a triangle
    2293528
    0.000000
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how to fix it?
I am desperate. Dev C++ is the only IDE i can understand. I've downloaded a couple others but can't figure them out.

Program: Orwell Dev-C++
Version: 5.3.0.4

Compiler: MinGW GCC 4.7.0 32bit (included with Dev-C++)

Comment: ***int*** main(), please...

Comment: Also, why are you passing pointers to poor printf? Have you read its documentation? (Hint: no, you haven't...)

Comment: Yeah my fault. I paid less attention to the poor buddy[actually mixed it up with scanf] @carbonic acid ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're feeding the addresses of those variables to a `printf()` which has been told to expect the values. This is undefined behaviour.

Just do:

```
printf("%c\n%d\n%f", a,x,y);
```